# Follow up question from: If p and q are prime which elements are in the subgroup? (GRE question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

original question: [If p and q are prime which elements are in the subgroup? (GRE question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231649/if-p-and-q-are-prime-which-elements-are-in-the-subgroup-gre-question)

I would simply like to ask a follow up question since I don't quite fully understand why the correct answer is correct.

The proper subset that can be a group from {$p$, $p+q$, $pq$, $p^q$, $q^p$} is {$p$, $pq$, $p^q$}. However, isn't $(pq + p^q)\notin H$ since $pq + p^q$ is greater than any element in H? I mean how do I convince myself that the set is closed under addition? What about existence of an identity and an inverse? Since those are the properties of a group that must be shown.

*This appeared as an exercise from chapter 2 of Gallian's book so I think I need to convince myself of the correct answer using only the definition of a group.

Comment: If you are supposing $H=\{p, pq, p^q\}$, then its not. It is actually $p, pq, p^q\in H$.

Comment: well the original question asks, "Suppose H is a proper subset" that contains **exactly** 3 elements. What does that mean then?

Comment: The `exactly' there was meant to restrict the elements of the five element set that can be in $H$ rather than the number of elements in $H$ itself, though I agree that it could have been said more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the question means is $H$ is a proper subset of the integers, which is a group under addition, and out of the five integers $p,p+q,pq,p^q,q^p$, exactly three of them are in $H$.

$H$ is a subgroup of the integers under addition, so it must be infinite (or $\{0\}$), so it certainly has to contain other integers not among those five.

In the answer you get $H=\{pk\mid k\in \mathbb Z\}$, and $H\cap \{p,p+q,pq,p^q,q^p\}=\{p,pq,p^q\}$.

(The way to see that no other $H$ works is that if $x,y$ are coprime and in $H$ you can write $1=ax+by$ for some integers $a,b$ and deduce that $H=\mathbb Z$, which isn't allowed. That means you can't have $p+q$ together with any of the other four. Similarly you can't have $q^p$ together with any of the others except $pq$, so if you have three they can't include $q^p$.)

Comment: why can't we have coprime integers in H?

Comment: Because $H$ is a subgroup, so if $x\in H$ then $x+\cdots+x\in H$, i.e. $nx\in H$ for any positive integer $n$. Also sicne $nx\in H$ you must have $-nx \in H$, so in fact any integer multiple of $x$ must be in $H$. The same applies to $y$, and then you can add $ax$ and $by$ to get $1\in H$. If $1\in H$ any integer multiple of $1$ is in $H$, so $H=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The fact that there exist integers $a,b$ with $ax+by=1$ is Bezout's lemma.

Comment: understood. thank you!